# Dwarfdump differences between OSX and Linux (and how to avoid them)

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, clang, dwarf

We're parsing the output of dwarfdump for our project but recently realized that the OSX output of dwarfdump is very different from the Linux output.

- Why are these different from each other and
- is it possible to make the OSX dwarfdump emit the same format as the Linux version?

We have already found [an older python script that supposedly translates the OSX output to the Linux format](https://code.google.com/p/volatility/source/browse/trunk/tools/mac/convert.py?r=2698), but that doesn't seem to work (anymore).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably process DWARF directly (using libdwarf for example) instead of parsing the text output of a program. I've converted some code which was doing the latter into the former and it was much better/robust after.

Comment: For me this worked: `dwarfdump --all ./executable.dwarf` FWIW

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `dwarfdump` reads ELF (executable format) and disassemble the session of debug information. However, on OSX, its executable format is Mach-O, so the tool name `dwarfdump` is not the same program, so it produces different results.

The one only similar tool I've used is `gobjdump`, and its usage and result is close to `readelf` on Linux platform. Using macports to get it

- Install macports.
- port install binutils
- gobjdump --dwarf=info path

For example, I run `gcc -gdwarf-2 a.c`, get `a.out` and `a.out.dSYM`

Then I can use `gobjdump --dwarf=info a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out` and get the output as follows:

```
a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out:     file format mach-o-x86-64

Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0xb2 (32-bit)
   Version:       2
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 : Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
       DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x1): 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)    
       DW_AT_language    : 1        (ANSI C)
       DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x40): a.c     
       DW_AT_entry_pc    : 0x100000ef0      
       DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0      
       DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x44): /tmp/       
 : Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_base_type)
       DW_AT_encoding    : 5        (signed)
       DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x56): int     
       DW_AT_byte_size   : 4        
 : Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
       DW_AT_sibling     :    
       DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x5a): main    
       DW_AT_MIPS_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x5a): main       
       DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
       DW_AT_decl_line   : 3        
       DW_AT_prototyped  : 1        
       DW_AT_type        :    
       DW_AT_external    : 1        
       DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x100000ef0      
       DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x100000f45      
       DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 56         (DW_OP_reg6 (rbp))
 : Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
 ...
```